# What are all ideals of $R/I^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. $I$ be a prime ideal of $R$.
What are all ideals of $R/I^n$ ?

By ideal correspondence, I only need to determine all ideals $J$,such that $I^n⊂J⊂R$.
I guess $0,I,I^2,・・・,I^n$ is all. But I cannot formally prove this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to classify the ideals. Even in the case of $I=\{0\}, n=1$, that would be to classify all the ideals of the integral domain $R\simeq R/I$, which is not possible in general.

Even if in the case of $I$ being maximal, this is still not true. Take e.g. $R=k[x, y]/(x^2, y^2, xy)=k\oplus kx\oplus ky$ where $k$ is a field (by abusing notation, we would write $x,y$ as if they are elements of the quotient ring) and $I$ be the ideal generated by $x, y$ which is definitely maximal, we have $I^2=0$, but between $0$ and $I$ there are many distinct ideals. In fact, any $k$-linear subspace of $kx\oplus ky$ is also a $R$-submodule.

Comment: Thank you ! Could you tell me what about when $R$ is ring of integers of imaginary quadratic field ?

Comment: Assume $I\not=0$, then for any Dedekind domain $\mathcal O$, this would be fine, due to the unique factorization of ideals into product of prime/maximal ideals.